# Example of shellable and non-shellable simplicial complexes with the same $f$-vector

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

I need to construct two pure simplicial complexes with the same $f$-vector such that one is shellable and one isn't. I think we can try two-dimensional simplicial complexes, I can find two simplicial complexes such that one is shellable and one isn't,  but they don't have the same $f$-vector.